# react native: how can I make the user edit a video/photo and save it in his gallery?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, video, video-editing

I want to make it so that once the user saves a video or chooses a video from their gallery can edit it and save it to their gallery. Like in Snapchat...
How can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: for image editing you can use this library : https://github.com/baronha/react-native-photo-editor

Comment: Ok thank you, but I would like to know how to transform an edited video/photo into a single video. (Like creating my own `react-native-photo-editor`.. I will check how this library is made.)